# Doctrine get full entity after a partial query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am working on a system that is build using Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine 2.

In this system I am working on the contracts part where I want a list with some data (a partial query) from all contracts and I need to fill in a form with all data (entity find) from a specific contract.

However, since the contract to be filled in the form is also a result of the partial query, the properties that had not been loaded in the PARTIAL query will not be loaded for the queried entity either.

I have simplified the data to show only the current issue, the real entity has more fields:

**Entity:**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ContractSub
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contract_sub", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="contract_id", columns={"contract_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="list_pension_start", columns={"list_pension_start_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="list_lease_car_category", columns={"list_lease_car_category_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="created_by_id", columns={"created_by_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Repository\ContractSubRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class ContractSub
{

    /**
     *
     * @var integer @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     *      @ORM\Id
     *      @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var \DateTime @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     *
     * @var \DateTime @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set startDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startDate            
     *
     * @return ContractSub
     */
    public function setStartDate($startDate)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartDate()
    {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set endDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endDate            
     *
     * @return ContractSub
     */
    public function setEndDate($endDate)
    {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEndDate()
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ContractSubRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getPartialStuffForTest()
    {
        $oQuery = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT PARTIAL ContractSub.{id, startDate} 
                                           FROM Application\Entity\ContractSub ContractSub');
        return $oQuery->getResult();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class ContractController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        $oEntityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $aContracts = $oEntityManager->getRepository('Application\Entity\ContractSub')->getPartialStuffForTest();
        $oContractSub = $oEntityManager->getRepository('Application\Entity\ContractSub')->find(38);
        var_dump($oContractSub->getStartDate());
        var_dump($oContractSub->getEndDate());
        die();
    }
}
```

**This outputs:**

```
object(DateTime)[479]
  public 'date' => string '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Amsterdam' (length=16)

null
```

Indicating that the `endDate` is not loaded, even though I do a `find` to retrieve the complete entity.
When I comment the line that executes the `getPartialStuffForTest()`, I do get the `endDate` as well.

So I was wondering if there is any way to force Doctrine to retrieve the full entity after it already has a cached version of the partial entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fully load a partial you have to use `$entityManager->refresh($object)`.

Your answer is in [the first paragraph in the Doctrine2 documentation chapter **18. Partial objects**](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html#partial-objects).

> Use of partial objects is tricky. Fields that are not retrieved from the database will not be updated by the `UnitOfWork` even if they get changed in your objects. You can only promote a partial object to a fully-loaded object by calling `EntityManager#refresh()` or a DQL query with the refresh flag.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I read over that. It is still not ideal in my scenario, as I sometimes in a function retrieve the full entity when the partial query was not done before, and sometimes retrieve the full entity which does not need a refresh. But at least I now know how to retrieve the full entity when needed. :)